# "Split in" vs "split into"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, into-in

In the sentence

> I have a bibliography page which I'd like to **split in/into** sections

which would you rather use: *split in* or *split into*?

Why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's not really a "grammatical" justification for the choice, but idiomatically, we [almost always](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=split%20in%20sections,split%20into%20sections&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) use *"into"* with *"sections"*...

[image]

...whereas with *"half"*, for example (there aren't many such examples), it's [the other way around](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=split%20in%20half,split%20into%20half&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

[image]

In fact, apart from *"half"* I'm not sure there's any other split you can make where *"into"* isn't preferred. If you compare [split in/into two](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=split%20in%20two,split%20into%20two&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), the preference isn't quite so marked - but that's probably influenced by the unusual usage with *"half"*. As you go to bigger numbers, the preference for *"into"* [is overwhelmingly reasserted](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=split%20in%20three,split%20into%20three&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

For a (weak) justification of the idiomatic preference for *split **into*** over *split **in***, I suggest that in numerous "compound verbs" *(lapse into a coma, descend into chaos, developed into full-blown AIDS, etc.)*, the *"into"* component strongly associates with "transformation" of the primary subject.

That association very much involves the "sub-component *"to"*, which can pass muster on its own in things like *turn to stone, bring to focus, etc.*. With those, you can get away with *"into"*, but you couldn't possibly use *"in"*.

Comment: I should have mentioned "please don't include the automatic Google NGRAM look-up" ;-) Don't take it wrong, please. Data-driven is to discover usage patterns, not so much for understanding (in my opinion, which is just that - an opinion).

Comment: @Robottinosino: Your question asked *"Which would you rather use?"* - to which any sane person would surely think *"If 99% of native speakers use one form rather than the other, that's what I'd rather use"*. I did address the issue of "understanding", by pointing out that there's no rule of grammar or logic involved - it's **idiomatic**. It just so happens that *"half"* goes against the normal idiomatic choice.

Comment: I respect your contribution, FumbleFingers. Please take no offence at my comment. As you defend it, it's a perfectly respectable data-driven response and I don't mean to dismiss NGRAM nor your point of view by my own comment. I happen to get no "linguistic" understanding out of NGRAM, that's all. I did not explicitly ask for that of answer either. BTW, I generally vote you up ;)

Comment: And I actually like your recent EDIT. I just disliked your cold, "just NGRAM it" initial answer.

Comment: @Robottinosino: You should edit your question if you're really interested in the *reason*, rather than just wanting to know which you (or anyone else) should normally "want" to use. Though I must admit if you *had* asked for a reason I'd probably have left it to John Lawler to answer - I think he's the current "site guru" when it comes to explaining idiomatic preferences for different prepositions used in this way. As for me, I learnt English the normal way - by hearing what others say, not by understanding the "rationale".

Comment: Good advice. Which incantations should one perform to conjure the Guru? ;)

Comment: @Robottinosino: haha. Apparently he was on-site only an hour ago! If you have the bottle, just find any of his existing questions and address a comment to him with a link to your question, asking if he would grace it with an answer. He's a very nice chap, so he might. On the other hand he might ignore you or give a curt reply, so you'd have to be ready to take that on the chin!

Comment: Nah, my chin is weak.

Comment: @Robottinosino: A good way to avoid getting Ngrams in the answers to your questions is to do them first, and then embed them in your question.  That way, everyone else can start from there, and address your concerns more directly.  Just a thought.

Comment: @FF: I liked your opening clause: _There's not really a "grammatical" justification for the choice..._  It is hard to put a finger on why we use "in" sometimes, and "into" other times.  In fact, if you change the Ngram to look for [_split in pieces_ vs _split into pieces_](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=split+in+pieces%2C+split+into+pieces&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), there's much less of a clear-cut favorite. As you indicated, sometimes one or the other will just sound more "right" (or maybe more "familiar"), but for no real rhyme or reason.

Comment: @J.R.: I'd still like to sick John Lawler on this one - I find he's excellent at explaining the underlying metaphoric associations that lead us to choose one "preposition" over another with these compound/phrasal verb combinations.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a bibliography page which I'd like to split in/into sections

So, there is this bibliography page that you **split in** most cases. Whatever you split, I hope you always **split into** sections, because I find it to be ---sections--- the best format to do so.

I have a bibliography page which I **splited into** twelve sections. Yes, I presented it **splitted in** a recent report. Don't be afraid to split; go ahead and split comfortably! Just don't ever *split into half* but **into halves** or **in half**.

;) Hope that helped. I would use *split into sections*.

From Oxford dictionary:

> **Divide or cause to divide into parts or elements**. ‘The river had split
>   into a number of channels’. ‘Splitting water into oxygen and
>   hydrogen’.
>
> **Example sentences**:
>
> ‘It left me absolutely dumbfounded to see the 25-foot high walls, to
>   see how towns have been split into two.’
>
> ‘He welcomed another measure now set to be adopted by the agency,
>   under which the westbound carriageway will be split into two separate
>   lanes.’
>
> ‘The development will be split into five separate blocks.’
>
> ‘Under the new scheme, the town centre will be split into 12 different
>   zones which council bosses claim could be cleared in minutes.’
>
> ‘It takes energy to split the water molecule and release hydrogen, but
>   that energy is later recovered during oxidation to produce water.’
>
> ‘The exam is split into 10 separate tests, which last from two minutes
>   to 18 minutes.’
>
> ‘The water molecule is split into hydrogen ions (positively charged
>   atoms) and oxygen.’
>
> ‘Classes, which last for 45 minutes, are split into separate sessions
>   for babies, one- to two-year-olds, and two- to four-year-olds.’
>
> ‘This electricity splits the water molecules in an electrolyte,
>   producing hydrogen.’
>
> ‘After much debate, it was split into two separate and distinct
>   countries.’
>
> ‘This resulted in two items being added, no items being dropped, one
>   item being split into two separate items, and one item having minor
>   wording changes.’
>
> ‘The program is split into three separate phases.’
>
> ‘Her hair was pulled back into a large ponytail which was split into
>   five separate braids.’
>
> ‘But when did the Olympics split into separate Summer and Winter
>   Games, and where were the first Winter Olympics held?’
>
> ‘The playing field is split into three separate areas: surface, air,
>   and underground.’
>
> ‘The cotton country on this farm is split into two separate
>   developments of about 1250 acres each.’
>
> ‘The flow of coolant when entering our heatsink base is split into six
>   separate channels and two separate directions.’
>
> ‘The response was split evenly - 44 percent didn't work; 44 percent
>   did work.’
>
> ‘The retail business of both his Florida and New Mexico stores was
>   split evenly between new and pre-owned vehicles.’
>
> ‘Sozopol is split into two main parts: the old town and new town -
>   known as Harmanite.’

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please consider editing your post into the form of an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I am very sorry you did not understand my answer; I though it was clear but maybe it was too cleverish. I hope it is clearer now. It is meant to help anybody, so any inquiries are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

We generally use 'into' to talk about directions and destinations, while we use 'in' to talk about the positions of thing. So you have to use 'split into' in your example because the destinations of the bibliography are the sections. 
However we might use:
(1)  'into' when we think of the division (split) itself; 
(2) 'in' when we think more at the end of division.

Comment: How can I put this into words? Bob was in trouble – his dad was in jail. I'll see you in ten minutes. Tomorrow we'll be in Texas, so we'd better get our papers in order. Bears hiberate in the winter. The probability of rolling doubles is one in six. I thought I heard them speaking in Spanish! After the election, the Labour Party is still in power. Ted is into classical music. Dave stumbled into the answer accidentally. Put some thought into this: ice melts into water, and water freezes into ice. (In other words, you might have oversimplified how these two words are used in speech).

Comment: @J.R. - Yes, you are correct. However I only tried to explain why 'into' IN THIS SPECIFIC case could be preferable in respect to 'in'. Thank you for the numerous examples you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Split in sections does not make any sense - you would have to split something **into** sections.

Comment: While I'm not sure if this was the OP's intention, you can have something _split in two_ or _split in three_. So why exactly can't you have something _split in sections_? I should note that Google returns 70000 hits for "split in sections" and Books returns 908. While many of them are either used in a different context or are false positives, some of them are used for a purpose similar to what the OP is considering.

Comment: @coleopterist: Per my own answer, *split in two* is in fact less common than *split **into** two*, and that difference becomes even more marked with *split in/into three*. In fact, with possibly the sole exception of *half* (and by association, *two*), *split in [anything]* is exceptionally uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

I think either one is acceptable.

The word *in* has well over 20 definitions, and one of them is *[into something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/in#in_29).*

So, I have no problem with *divide this page into three sections.*  Moreover, I would accept *divide this page in three sections,* although the former seems to sound a bit more natural to me.

As an example of how vexing this could be, I'd probably say:

> Cut this candy bar **in** half.

but also:

> Cut this candy bar **into** thirds.

Comment: Probably, in your examples (divide...into/in...) we might use 'into' when we think of the division itself, while 'in' when we think more at the end of division.